# Android, is it possible to animate TextView.setGravity()?

Tags: android, gravity, programmatically-created

I have a situation where I would like to programmatically change the gravity of my text view (`Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL`|`Gravity.BOTTOM` to `Gravity.START`|`Gravity.BOTTOM`). Currently I'm using the `setGravity()` method, but I'm wondering if there is anyway to set this to smoothly transition over to the new position rather than just jumping to the new discrete position.

Thanks, 
Hugh

Comment: Better use Translation Animation if you are looking for smooth animation

Comment: Adding animation on Gravity change is not supported intrinsically by AOSP, however there is always a way arround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-organizing my layout leaving the problem moot. Still not a solution to what I was asking though.